# How can I animate an interior scene from day to night?

Tags: animation, light

I have a basic isometric interior room and I want to animate how this room looks when the sun goes down and it becomes dark, day to night.

Something like these videos, **[01](https://youtu.be/j_OROHzLw3w), [02](https://youtu.be/bC2Uq8-em1s)**

So I'm wondering how to animate skytexture and sun to look like that, or if there's another way.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Cycles?

Comment: Nicola Sap yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Cycles or Eevee

#### Light your scene with:

- a world node setup using a *Mix* node between two *Environment textures*:

  1. a nightlight texture like [this](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=night&h=shanghai_bund)
  2. a not too bright daylight texture without a visible sun direction (highly overcast) like [this](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=overcast&h=potsdamer_platz), because you will like to add and animate the Sun yourself
- a sun lamp with some "midday" inclination, parented to an Empty that stays at ground level in the middle of the scene (you could also put the sun lamp directly in the middle, but with an Empty it "looks" nicer while you work on it).
- indoor lights

#### Animate by setting these keyframes:

- Starting frame:

  - the Empty is rotated such that the sun is high in the sky.
  - The sun Energy is high. The sun color can be slightly orange if the daylight world texture is slightly blue
  - The world Mix factor is at 1.0 (completely daylight)
  - *no keyframes for indoor lights*
- at ~80% of the transition

  - indoor lights Energy is zero
  - *no keyframes for world/sun*
- at ~80% of the transition + a few frames

  - indoor lights Energy is high
  - *no keyframes for world/sun*
- Last frame:

  - The Empty is rotated along either the X or the Y axis in a way such that the sun goes just slightly below (and parallel to) the horizon
  - The sun Energy is zero. The sun color is neutral.
  - The world Mix factor is at 0.0
  - *no keyframes for indoor lights*

Comment: thank you so much, your explanations are so good. I might share my result later if you're intrested.

Comment: @eve of course, anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Octane Blender (free edition) has a sweet world shader with day / night cycle of which you can animate the time, latitude and longitude etc. I made this video with it: 
[image]
https://youtu.be/FND8RX6cHPo